# algebra with fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

While studying math, I have come across this problem:

$$x < \frac x3 + \frac 23$$

Now according to the textbook, the answer is $x < 1$, but I can't see how they came up with that solution, as I could only come up with the answer $x < x + 2$.
So I'd appreciate it if someone could explain this to me.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting $\frac{x}{3}$ from both sides
$$\frac{2x}{3}<\frac23$$
Multiplying both sides by
$\frac32$
gives
$$x<1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x<\frac x3+\frac23\stackrel{\cdot3}\implies3x<x+2\stackrel{-x}\implies 2x<2\stackrel{\div2}\implies x<1$$

Observe that all the involved operations, carried on both sides of the inequality, do **not** change the inequality sign...

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer would be:

\begin{align}x&<\frac x3 +\frac 23\\\\
x&<\frac{x+2}{3}\tag{combine fractions}\\\\
3x&<x+2\tag{multiply by $3$}\\
2x&<2\tag{subtract $x$}\\
x&<1\tag{divide by $2$}\end{align}

Your answer is close, it appears that when you multiplied by $3$, you only multiplied the right hand side of the equation, and not also the left, leaving you with $x<x+2$ when you should have had $3x<x+2$

Answer (score 0):

$x-\frac x3 < \frac 23$

$\frac{2x}{3} < \frac 23$

$2x < 2$

$x<1$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
&x < (x/3) + (2/3)\\[4pt]
\iff\; &3x < 3{\large{(}}(x/3) + (2/3){\large{)}}\\[4pt]
\iff\; &3x < 3(x/3) + 3(2/3)\\[4pt]
\iff\; &3x < x + 2\\[4pt]
\iff\; &2x < 2\\[4pt]
\iff\; &x < 1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}